# accelerometer data processing, time drift and fft

Tags: fft, sampling, time-series

We have have a small data cleaning issue we would like to share.

Context: We have data from an accelerometer sensor worn at the hip. We set the device so that data are collected at a sampling rate of 100 Hz. We perform a 10-sec window analysis in order to extract several features of interest, some of them being obtained from a FFT analysis. The ultimate goal is to  develop algorithms predicting some selected physical behaviors (gait frequency or less, so <3-4Hz).

Problem: We have noticed a small time drift when looking at the sample timestamps. For a window of 10 sec, we should have 1000 samples, but we noted that the actual number of samples can be between 993 and 1005.

Question: When running the FFT function (see [scipy.fft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/fft.html)), should we indicate the actual frequency (sometimes closer to 99Hz or 101Hz) or should we keep 100Hz for all window? Considering the observed phenomena (let's say "walking gait", ~3Hz), we think that the this small 1Hz error does not affect the outcome of the FFT analysis.
But, we are wondering whether it would not be better to "respace" samples (and interpolate data where the respacing process creates wholes in the series)
What would be the best practice here from a signal processing perspective?

Thanks for helping.

[Edit addressing Irreducible's question]. We "chop" the 10-sec windows based on timestamps, i.e. from window start to nearest sample found before "start +10 sec". This results in windows having 1000 +/-5 samples (the time drift may be slightly different from windows to windows, but stays very small, resulting in actual sampling within the 99-101 Hz range over one given window). Sorry for the confusion, windows are not strictly 10 sec, otherwise we would not have any problem, they are approximately 10 seconds, i.e. 10000 milliseconds more or less 10-50 milliseconds.

[Edit addressing Jdip's comment]. Without entering too much in the protocol details, we used several accelerometer units (same type). Considering each unit separately, the drift does not change much over time, but still changes a bit. For example: 1005, 1005, 1005, 1004, 1004, 1005... (samples). Another unit might be: 995, 995, 993, 994... sensor outputs are not fused.

Comment: It is unclear to me, how you extract the 10sec windows? I would assumed you chop it manually depending on the sampling rate and the duration of your window, which would always result in the expected number of samples?

Comment: @Irreducible's comment should be taken as an answer: if you know the "time drift", just adapt the length of the window ( so that it is always 10s ).

Comment: Thank you very much @Irreducible for the inputs. I just added some edits in the original message.  We used timestamps to chop window of approximatively 10-sec ( <10ms approximation). The expected number of samples should be 1000, but we actually have less or more samples (reflecting a time drift): 992-1005. For one data acquisition of ~10 min, the time drift does not vary much (but is not constant). Ex: 1005,1005,1004,1004,1004,1005. Or: 993,993,993,994,993 for another sensor/acquisition.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jdip for the inputs. As you suggested, we know the window actual duration (we work with timestamps) and can indicate the exact sampling rate when performing the FFT analysis, but is it really necessary to do it considering that it will always be in the 99-101 Hz range (gait-events occurs below 10 Hz). We already tried different types of processing and it does not seem to impact the results of the subsequent machine-learning analysis. The question is about what would be the best practice/aesthetic from a signal processing perspective. (see the edit in the original message).

Comment: What model DAQ are you using to collect the data? 0.5% drift is excessive. Maybe post your code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Are you doing this in real time or are we talking about post processing? In the case you do it offline, why dont you work on the data directly without the consideration of the timestamps, especially when there is such a variation?

Comment: Thank you @Ash ! We use wearable sensor from mbientlab with the default library for data acquisition (no DAQ). What I understand from my search on the issue is that cheap accelerometer chips like the one found in smartphones/wearable devices may come with flaws, which apparently do not impair operations (screen orientation, evaluation of physical behavior, etc.). Still, I am surprised about such a "high" drift rate.

Comment: Thanks @Irreducible ! At this stage of the project, we are doing post-processing. Yes, as you suggested we "naively" started to cut windows relatively to the number of samples (here 1000 samples for an expected 10 sec). However, when we noticed the time drift, we changed for the timestamp method, since sliding window analytic methods are usually describe window relatively to their duration (even when called length), rather than their number of samples.

Comment: Why not build a  computer model that has exposed controls that correspond to the "errors" you are seeing?  That way you could test post-processing techniques under different  conditions/errors.